# CPU usage goes to 100% when I lock the screen

Tags: 12.04, cpu, fan, lock

Whenever I lock the screen, after a certain amount of time, the CPU and the CPU fan go to their limits, and they return back to normal the moment I unlock the screen again (as shown by `psensor`).

How can I find out what process is responsible for this?

I've tried with "top -S", and the result is this...

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND    
 2114 me       20   0  326m 104m  40m R   16  2.6  66:50.03 compiz     
 1234 root     20   0  396m 152m  98m R    6  3.8  20:23.88 Xorg       
 2204 me       20   0  160m  38m  30m S    4  1.0   0:33.35 yakuake    
 2446 me       20   0  206m  18m  12m S    4  0.5   6:32.18 psensor    
 2280 me       20   0  220m  18m  10m S    2  0.5   5:01.60 unity-panel
 9138 me       20   0  154m  27m  15m S    2  0.7   0:03.63 plugin-cont
 2282 me       20   0 65800 5272 3316 S    1  0.1   4:36.90 hud-service
 2143 me       20   0  140m  11m 8352 S    1  0.3   2:50.16 indicator-m
 9095 me       20   0  720m 253m  36m S    1  6.4   0:26.34 firefox    
 2076 me       20   0  7168 3484  828 S    1  0.1   1:46.53 dbus-daemon
 2307 me       20   0 55000 5132 3632 S    1  0.1   2:01.55 indicator-a
 2557 me       20   0 86328 6028 4576 S    0  0.1   1:44.71 conky      
 6290 me       20   0  2836 1296  964 R    0  0.0   0:29.64 top        
 6291 me       20   0  2836 1188  884 S    0  0.0   0:29.49 top        
   1 root      20   0  3644 1984 1284 S    0  0.0  60:57.76 init
```

Specs:

- Fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.04
- Intel Core i5
- 4 GB RAM

Comment: What screensaver are you using? Some of these do take a considerable amount of resources.

Comment: None, the screen is set to turn off after a certain amount of time.

Comment: The screen, but not necessarily the processing involved in generating the displays.

Comment: the screen lock itself via the standard preferences menu "brightness and lock", or I lock it manually via ctrl-alt-l

Comment: yes, it is should be that, I didn't add any screensaver

Comment: Also, I think if  "locking" is taking place, this passes a command to a screensaver (gnome-screensaver, or xscreensaver, e.g.) or something like xlock.

Comment: On vanilla Unity, I believe this is actually gnome-screensaver with the blank screen option.  I will try to verify (I've replaced mine with xscreensaver).

Comment: Can you post output from `dpkg -l | grep screensaver` ?

Comment: ii  gnome-screensaver 3.4.1-0ubuntu1 GNOME screen saver and locker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [[fglrx] compiz uses 100% CPU when screen turns off (..)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/969860) is your problem as well. Then here is what you can try to do:

> WORKAROUND:
>
> 1. Open Catalyst Control Center.
> 2. Go to 3D > More Settings.
> 3. Set "Wait for vertical refresh" to "On, unless application specifies".
>      And if that doesn't work, then also do:
> 4. Run "ccsm"
> 5. In Workarounds, enable "Force full screen redraw (buffer swap) on repaint".

Please, also mark the bug as "This bug affects me" if it should be the case.

Comment: thanks to Mark and to all the others that suggested me to look at the gnome-screensaver, which I had supposed to be inactive :-)

Answer (score 3):

To find out which processes use the CPU while the screen is locked, use

```
top -b -i > watch.txt
```

and lock the screen. Wait a while, then look at the file. I found out that compiz and emacs are having a lot of fun while I am away.

Answer (score 3):

For users who has "similar" problem:
It is important to distinguish if CPU usage goes up

- when screensaver "activates" OR
- when lock screen activates.

As far as I see from comments this can be mixed up easily (I mixed up as well for the first time).

To distuinguish:

- in terminal run "top" (or use "system-monitor" GUI where CPU usage past is visible),
- Press Alt-Ctrl-L (immediate screen lock),
- wait 3-4 secs (10-20 secs for "system-monitor"),
- unlock computer and
- IMMEDIATELY press "q" - to quit from "top" (or just check the last minutes of CPU usage in "system-monitor")

If there was a high CPU, you have NOTHING TO DO with screensaver, because screensaver has not activated. This is the case with my system.

I created an official Ubuntu bug, but realized there is a bug related to this, so I linked: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1322751

I wrote down a quite brutal workaround there. Please use it if you understood what that script is doing - and it suits for you.

It seems that fairly decent Intel "Haswell" or newer CPU/GPU-s are affected.

Please tick "This bug affects you" if it is true.