# Compiz uses insane amount of CPU

Tags: unity, drivers, graphics, ati, compiz

On my machine, Compiz uses ~25% of all 8 cores when I use the computer.
When I *don't* use it (so it's idle), Compiz uses around 50%.
***How do I make compiz not use so much CPU?***

I've struggled with this problem for *years* and it's annoying. My computer is a monster, but `compiz` is crippling it, and it's loudest and hottest *when it's idle.* I can't believe there is anything in Ubuntu that requires that much work *all the time* and especially not during idle.

- OS = Ubuntu 15.04 (wondering whether upgrading to 15.10 would help, but [probably not](https://askubuntu.com/a/688757/5786)?)
- DE = I use and like Unity (please don't suggest alternatives)
- CPU = Intel i7, 16GB RAM
- `lspci | grep VGA` = AMD Radeon 5450 ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/72774/5786))
- `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` = Not software rendered:    no ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/383668/5786))
- `About this computer` = Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.6, 128 bits)
- I don't currently have AMD drivers installed; last time I battled the compiz monster, I had big trouble even getting an image on the monitor. I'll take this challenge again if I have to, to make this compiz problem go away. OTOH downloading AMD drivers and using Catalyst seems to be not recommended ([example source](https://askubuntu.com/a/630243/5786)).
- `ccsm` = Sync to VBlank is not ticked, and Texture Filter is "Fast". ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/162913/5786))
- `ccsm` = As an experiment, I've now enabled "Force full screen redraw (buffer swap) on repaint". ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/148502/5786))

Comment: Discussed before? http://askubuntu.com/questions/128649/compiz-using-8-25-cpu-continually

Comment: @jdv yes as I said, I've been battling this monster for years, and that link is also in my post. The listed suggestions don't help, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the `About this computer = Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.6, 128 bits)` line - this indicates that the CPU is doing all of the graphics processing, and compiz takes a lot!

You can try the oibaf drivers, available on [lanchpad](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers), or look for a proprietary driver for your card.

[this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329579/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-or-amd-graphic-drivers-and-other-drivers-in-ubuntu-1) has a good, although dated, response about installing AMD drivers.

I don't have experience with the Radeon drivers myself, but I have seen numerous comments about issues.  All of the comments that I have seen have a common thread:  The operator got the driver working and then did a major version upgrade (like 15.04 to 15.10) and found that something broke.  Often, the upgrade documentation will state directly that disabling proprietary drivers is required.

To check if Ubuntu knows about proprietary drivers for your system, hit the meta key, and start the program 'Additional Drivers'

Comment: Thank you Charles; that was also my hunch as I wrote this question. May I ask on what basis you suggest "oibaf" drivers, as I've not come across this before? And by "proprietary" do you mean the built-in "fglrx" drivers, or those that must be downloaded from amd.com?

Comment: I use the oibaf drivers with an intel graphcis system, works great - they are between the built-in drivers and the cutting-edge drivers in terms of performance.  Proprietary:  The maker of the card does not release the source code for the driver, so Ubuntu does not include them normally.  Sometimes they work well, other times....

Comment: "[this question]" seems to be missing a link, right?

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun  sigh.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun  Updated answer....

Comment: Okay - I took the plunge and selected "fglrx" in "Additional Drivers", hoping it wouldn't cause me trouble. And -- it worked! `unity_support_test` now reports software rendering "off", and compiz seems to saty below 3%. Phew! Thank you again.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun Great!  Just remember when you go to upgrade your system, removing the AMD drivers first, and reinstalling them later will make life a lot sweeter.

Comment: Thanks buddy - that's the kind of thing I'm likely to forget *despite* being told about it... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: To solve *exactly this problem* the right way, see http://askubuntu.com/a/772032/233794.