# fglrx messes with my windows

Tags: unity, drivers, graphics, ati, fglrx

I've just [solved one problem](https://askubuntu.com/a/694038/5786) with my graphics, only to run into a new one. I've got an ATI Radeon card and I've installed the Ubuntu-included fglrx drivers for it. That gave me hardware-supported graphics, which is nice.

However, now I got a new problem:  My (up to date) Chrome browser frequently gets its content messed up -- sometimes the tab bar, sometimes the page contents:
[image: click to embiggify]
That did not use to happen so I believe it's directly linked to the switch to fglrx. I was using default Ubuntu drivers before.
--> How can I fix this (without losing hardware graphics support again)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Chrome is the only thing affected, try [this](http://ccm.net/faq/35743-google-chrome-how-to-disable-hardware-acceleration):

> To disable the hardware acceleration feature of Google Chrome follow
>   the below procedure:
>
> ```
> Open Google Chrome.
> Click Customize and Control Google Chrome > Settings.
> Click on "Show advanced settings" and scroll to the "System" section.
> Uncheck "Use hardware acceleration when available" and restart Google Chrome.
> ```

If hardware acceleration is not enabled, try using it. In other words, toggle the setting.

Comment: Yes, so far I've only noticed this problem inside Chrome. I've toggled the setting you mention (it was on, so now it's off) and I'll pay attention to see if it helps. Thank you!

Comment: Accepted! Problem hasn't appeared anywhere since I toggled this.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  That 'hardware acceleration' setting has caused problems on a number of our family computers.